# How to compute the time between adjacent documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a mongodb database with millions of documents representing events. Each document is timestamped. I want to evaluate the elapsed between events. Longer times are more significant than shorter times. How can this be done efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get the following code to work.

```
db.main.find()
    .forEach(function(doc){
        //print('got1 id: ' + doc._id);
        db.main.find({'_id': {$gt: doc._id}, user: doc.user})
               .sort({'_id': 1})
               .limit(1)
               .forEach(function(doc2){
                    //print('got2 id: ' + doc2._id);
                    print(doc._id + ': ' + (ISODate(doc2.startT).getTime() - ISODate(doc.startT).getTime()));
                })
        }
    );
```

There may be other ways to solve this which I would also be interested in as I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think a short answer is that this probably isn't going to be something that you can compute using a query. Your tag for this suggests that you might be looking for a query to compute this, but I don't think that's going to be possible.

It also doesn't sound like something like map reduce would work here, either.

If you literally need the computed differences between every single event, then you're probably going to need to look into crunching over those values and storing the results somewhere. Or, you could compute them up front as you insert each new event and store them somewhere.

Regardless, it just sounds like you're going to need to write something that computes that on its own agenda and stores the result somewhere for you.